# CMake: find_library result depends on selected compiler?

Tags: linux, cmake

I'm confused about how `find_library` is supposed to work, and I don't know if this could be a CMake bug, or a misuse or misconfiguration on my part. I have installed both GCC and PGI compilers, and when I try this simple `CMakeLists.txt` file (with both 2.8.11 and 3.5.1):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
find_library( LIBdl dl )
message("LIBdl ${LIBdl}")
```

I get the following:

```
$ CC=gcc CXX=g++ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
LIBdl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/molcas-test/test/cmake
```

That's OK, but:

```
$ CC=pgcc CXX=pgc++ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is PGI 17.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is PGI 17.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/pgi/linux86-64/17.1/bin/pgcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/pgi/linux86-64/17.1/bin/pgcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/pgi/linux86-64/17.1/bin/pgc++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/pgi/linux86-64/17.1/bin/pgc++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
LIBdl LIBdl-NOTFOUND
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/molcas-test/test/cmake
```

Note `dl` was not found.

Leaving out either `pgcc` or `pgc++` causes the library to be found, so it must be something in how the compilers are configured. And yet just compiling from the command line finds `dl` without complain:

```
$ pgcc -ldl hello_world.c -o hello_world
$ ./hello_world
Hello world!
```

So I believe something's not right if `pgcc` can find the library and CMake can't. I could of course set `LIB=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` before running `cmake`, to force a search in that directory, but that doesn't feel right.

It seems the problem is with `gcc`. I get `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` included in `CMAKE_C_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES`, so `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` is set. But with `pgcc` this directory is absent and `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` is empty.

And the directory is missing with `pgcc`, because `pgcc -v` doesn't include a `-L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` flag, while `gcc -v` does. However, `ld` finds libraries in the directory in either case.

So CMake is not searching libraries in the same places as `ld`. Should it? Is there an easy way to change this, other than, e.g., manually inspecting all files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` and setting the `LIB` environment variable?

Comment: CMake docs say that `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` is deduced from the compiler. I'd say it does something like `gcc -dumpmachine` which gives `x86_64-linux-gnu`. Apparently it's something else for `pgcc`. You can always check and compare everything with `strace`. To keep all the confusion in one place, write a toolchain file specifically for `pgcc`.

Comment: @Velkan As far as I understand `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` is deduced from the "implicit link directories", which are read from the `(p)gcc -v` flags.

Comment: @Jellby indeed, cmake's `find_library()` function runs the compiler driver to compile and link a test program with `-v` and then searches the directories prefixed with `-L` in the output (in the invocation of `collect2` in case of gcc).